# Tkinter python GUI issue

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a menu for my term project and I am running into a issue.

I want a left pane for my controls and on the right there will be visulization but when i run the code an un wanted space is created on the top left area because of the t1.pack() and c1.pack()

Please help me how can i get two clear panes.

Let me know if you didnt get the issue.

Thanks in advance :)

```
__author__ = 'sagar'
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # for python 3
except:
    #import Tkinter as tk  # for python 2
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk as ttk
    import ctypes
    import tkMessageBox

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
WIDTH,HEIGHT = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0),user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
WIDTH -= 50
HEIGHT -= 75

class Application: #pygubu.TkApplication
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root

        self.fr_main = Frame(self.root,background="grey",highlightcolor="red")
        self.fr_main.grid(row=0,column=0,ipadx=(5*WIDTH)/100,ipady=HEIGHT)
        # self.fr_main.pack()

        self.btn_Simulator = Button(self.fr_main,text="Simulator")
        self.btn_Simulator.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10)
        # self.btn_Simulator.pack()

        self.btn_Analysis = Button(self.fr_main,text="Analysis")
        self.btn_Analysis.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=10)
        # self.btn_Analysis.pack()


        self.fr_second = Frame(self.root,background="black",highlightcolor="red")
        self.fr_second.grid(row=0,column=1,ipadx=(40*WIDTH)/100,ipady=HEIGHT)
        self.nb_main = ttk.Notebook(self.fr_second)
        self.nb_main.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)


        f1 = Frame(self.nb_main)
        f2 = Frame(self.nb_main)

        self.nb_main.add(f2,text="Canvas")
        self.nb_main.add(f1,text="Calculation")

        t1 = Text(f1)
        c1 = Canvas(f2)
        c1.configure(background="black")
        t1.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)
        c1.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)


    def __controlState__(self,control,state):
        control.configure(state =state)

    def showName(self,Enableframe,DisableFrame):

        for child in Enableframe.winfo_children():
            Enableframe.config(relief = RAISED)
            self.__controlState__(child,"active")

        for child in DisableFrame.winfo_children():
            self.__controlState__(child,"disable")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.title("Network Simulator")


    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (WIDTH,HEIGHT,0,0))
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please help me how can i get two clear panes.

The absolute simplest way to get two frames side-by-side that take up the whole height of the window is to use `pack` with appropriate options:

```
self.fr_main.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
self.fr_second.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

The key is that the first one needs to be on the left or right side, filling in the "y" direction. After that, the second one can be on any side as long as it fills in both directions.

If you want to use `grid`, make sure to include the `sticky` option so that the frames fill the space given to them:

```
self.fr_main.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.fr_second.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

With `grid`, you'll also want to give the columns weight so that grid knows how to allocate extra space

```
self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```